# How to Host .NET 4.5 Web Applications in Windows Server 2008 Standard?

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-mvc-5, windows-server-2008, asp.net-4.5

### I'm trying to host:

- ASP.NET MVC 5 applications

on:

- Windows Server 2008 Standard

I have already installed **.NET 4.5** on the server, but the server won't give me the option to install the feature or service: **ASP.NET 4.5** as shown below:

[image]

Shown above, it only gives the option to add the service **ASP.NET**. What's needed is **ASP.NET 4.5**.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You just need to install .NET Framework 4.5 and then run aspnet_regiis command.

Comment: Can you enlighten me more on the aspnet_regiis command?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx

Comment: Looking up on it. Thanks!

Comment: You interpreted the Microsoft info wrongly. It is only Server Core edition that fails to support .NET Framework. If you can see Server Manager, that means you are not using Server Core, and .NET Framework should be installed without a problem.

Comment: Oh sorry. But I have already installed .NET 4.5 on the server. But the problem is it can't host .NET 4.5 applications. It won't let me add that service shown in the image from the question.

Comment: ASP.NET 4 and 4.5 won't appear in Server Manager no matter what you change on Windows Server 2008. `aspnet_regiis` does exactly the same thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84753/discussion-between-don-cadavona-and-lex-li).